# `useResizeContainer` throwing errors when using `happy-dom` as test environment

Tags: reactjs, testing, material-ui, vitest

When mounting a DataGrid in a test suite using `happy-dom`, it throws the error:

```
MUI: useResizeContainer - The parent DOM element of the data grid has an empty height.Please make sure that this element has an intrinsic height.The grid displays with a height of 0px.
```

even though the parent container has a set height.

I tried replacing `happy-dom` with `jsdom` and the error did went away. However, I'm not interested in using the latter in this project. I also tried adding parent containers with fixed and percentage widths and heights without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a width and height on the parent element.

Another solution is to define a size on all elements by changing the prototype of the Element class. This can be done during setup.

**Defining a size on only the parent element**

```
Object.defineProperty(parentElement, 'width', { get: () => 100 });
Object.defineProperty(parentElement, 'height', { get: () => 100 });
```

**Defining a size on all elements**

```
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'width', { get: () => 100 });
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'height', { get: () => 100 });
```

Comment: Tried both solutions, but the warning won't go away.

Comment: It might now use the height property. You could try other properties like "offsetWidth" and "offsetHeight".